# What is a 'FrameFixed' Object in python?

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,4), columns = list('ABCD'))
with pd.HDFStore("test.h5") as store:
    store['df'] = df
with pd.HDFStore("test.h5") as store:
    print store.select_as_coordinates('df')
```

This gave me an attribute error with

```
----> 3     print store.select_as_coordinates(keys[1])
C:\...\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in select_as_coordinates(self, key, where, start, stop, **kwargs)
    755         """
    756         where = _ensure_term(where, scope_level=1)
--> 757         return self.get_storer(key).read_coordinates(where=where, start=start,
    758                                                      stop=stop, **kwargs)
    759 

AttributeError: 'FrameFixed' object has no attribute 'read_coordinates'
```

I tried looking for `FrameFixed` objects in python but was not successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback please

Comment: @lee-pai-long added some of the traceback

Comment: What version of panda do you use ?

Comment: @lee-pai-long 20.3 I believe. `pandas.__version__` gives me 20.3

Comment: `HDFStore` can have `format` `fixed` or `table`.  It looks like `fixed` is the earlier default, `table` the newer, more flexible format.  `FrameFixed` is a class defined in `pandas/io/pytables.py`.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I'll take a look at the pytables file